# How can I merge two data sets when the using data set is a subset of the master data set? Stata

Tags: merge, stata

I have three data sets I would like to `merge`: one contains data on all members of a household and the other two contain more detailed data on women and men respectively.

I would like to link my detailed data to the household data. See an example of the data sets below. I need to use household ID (HH ID) and individual ID (IND ID) to link to bolded observations. Once the women and men data are `merge`d there will still be some missing observations that do appear in the household data (which I would like to keep).

Household data set

| HH ID | IND ID |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** |
| 1 | 2 |
| **1** | **3** |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |
| **2** | **2** |
| 2 | 3 |
| **3** | **1** |

Women's data set

| HH ID | IND ID |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** |
| **1** | **3** |
| **2** | **2** |
| **3** | **1** |

I have tried the following 1:1 `merge`

`merge 1:1 hhid indid using "womens_data.dta"`

and got the following error message,

```
variables hhid indid do not uniquely identify observations in the master data
r(459);
```

What should I be doing instead?

Comment: The error means that you have duplicates in `hhid` and `indid` (for example there are two rows with `hhid==1` and `indid==3`) in the household dataset at the same time you use `1:1` indicating that should not be the case. So, your code is correct, but something you assume about your dataset is not correct. Run `duplicates report hhid indid` in the household data and make sure you understand why some combinations of `hhid` and `indid` are duplicated.

Comment: You're right, I did have some duplicates which I hadn't realised. Thank you, it works perfectly now :)